# Scrape page links

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-inspector

I want to scrape this site page link https://kw.com/agent/search/IL/Chicago but this page inspection doesn't have any div class or a `href` link. I don't understand which function needs to call to scrape these 652 agent links.

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://kw.com/agent/search/IL/Chicago'
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')

urls = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

This code is working for other pages but this site looks complicated to me. How can I collect these site links?

Comment: So you need to extract all the names link from here right?

Comment: Yes, the names link

Comment: Yes, selenium and chrome web driver is installed on my device (pycharm) and working fine (tested)

Comment: It will be very good for me.

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't make it clear. When i click on the names it takes to another page Like Maryam Abdi to https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6762861760017670144-8. Actually I want to collect these links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually , all required data is generating from API. Each agent link/url contains a unique Id and this id value with the domain name is the agent link/details page link.

**Example:**

```
import requests

api_url = "https://api-endpoint.cons-prod-us-central1.kw.com/graphql"
data={"operationName":"searchAgentsQuery","variables":{"searchCriteria":{"searchTerms":{"param1":"IL","param2":"Chicago"}},"first":50,"after":"99","queryId":"0.8691595723322416"},"query":"query searchAgentsQuery($searchCriteria: AgentSearchCriteriaInput, $first: Int, $after: String) {\n  SearchAgentQuery(searchCriteria: $searchCriteria) {\n    result {\n      agents(first: $first, after: $after) {\n        edges {\n          node {\n            ...AgentProfileFragment\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        pageInfo {\n          ...PageInfoFragment\n          __typename\n        }\n        totalCount\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment PageInfoFragment on PageInfo {\n  endCursor\n  hasNextPage\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment AgentProfileFragment on AgentProfileType {\n  id\n  name {\n    full\n    given\n    initials\n    __typename\n  }\n  image\n  location {\n    address {\n      state\n      city\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  realEstateEntity {\n    name\n    __typename\n  }\n  specialties\n  languages\n  isAgentLuxuryEnabled\n  phone {\n    entries {\n      ... on ContactSetEntryMobile {\n        number\n        __typename\n      }\n      ... on ContactSetEntryEmail {\n        email\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  agentLicenses {\n    licenseNumber\n    state\n    __typename\n  }\n  marketCenter {\n    market_center_name\n    market_center_address1\n    market_center_address2\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n"}
headers={
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'x-datadog-origin': 'rum',
        'x-datadog-parent-id': '5420198475190660541',
        'x-datadog-sampled': '1',
        'x-datadog-sampling-priority': '1',
        'x-datadog-trace-id': '1837163169752685118',
        'x-shared-secret': 'MjFydHQ0dndjM3ZAI0ZHQCQkI0BHIyM='
}

res = requests.post(api_url,headers=headers,json=data)
data = res.json()['data']['SearchAgentQuery']['result']['agents']['edges']

for item in data:
        link='https://kw.com/agent/' + item['node']['id']
        print(link)
```

**Output:**

```
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385404419399681-8
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385313789222917-3
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6704789234247561216-6
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385427490459656-4
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385454284918792-0
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6882009464351350784-8
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6937439716674322432-5
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385379476373510-1
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6853411032351416320-2
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385065789456390-4
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385175436890114-3
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6942951019140222976-1
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6808491123018551296-7
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385273946116100-8
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385281007677447-9
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6592268954554945544-5
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385270364864517-7
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6856325267405185024-3
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6804158392167718912-3
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6638843865929490435-1
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587384999272361984-6
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6592267095708119045-4
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385271389274119-4
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385271385079815-8
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385288161681409-1
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385375965011973-7
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385274994008066-1
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6913250263682408448-6
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385272597565443-9
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6859526404702093312-9
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385390518407175-2
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385436077776899-8
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587384956740640770-9
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385297339674632-1
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385390593904641-1
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6811013526642786304-3
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6932834317516042240-9
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385437068947458-5
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385380989808647-6
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6892926376478015488-5
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6905262704995926016-2
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6592947303925784578-6
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385393920495624-5
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6783788552269369344-7
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6710285049427382272-8
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6844700377378430976-0
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6934540598372548608-6
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6711387287014834176-1
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385367301132290-0
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6714648183099023360-3
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
import requests
import json

url = "https://api-endpoint.cons-prod-us-central1.kw.com/graphql"
payload = {
    "operationName": "searchAgentsQuery",
    "variables": {
        "searchCriteria": {
            "searchTerms": {
                "param1": "IL",
                "param2": "Chicago"
            }
        },
        "first": 652,  # Change this to change the number of agents returned
        "after": "",
        "queryId": "0.5045631892889886"
    },
    "query": "query searchAgentsQuery($searchCriteria: AgentSearchCriteriaInput, $first: Int, $after: String) {\n  SearchAgentQuery(searchCriteria: $searchCriteria) {\n    result {\n      agents(first: $first, after: $after) {\n        edges {\n          node {\n            ...AgentProfileFragment\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        pageInfo {\n          ...PageInfoFragment\n          __typename\n        }\n        totalCount\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment PageInfoFragment on PageInfo {\n  endCursor\n  hasNextPage\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment AgentProfileFragment on AgentProfileType {\n  id\n  name {\n    full\n    given\n    initials\n    __typename\n  }\n  image\n  location {\n    address {\n      state\n      city\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  realEstateEntity {\n    name\n    __typename\n  }\n  specialties\n  languages\n  isAgentLuxuryEnabled\n  phone {\n    entries {\n      ... on ContactSetEntryMobile {\n        number\n        __typename\n      }\n      ... on ContactSetEntryEmail {\n        email\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  agentLicenses {\n    licenseNumber\n    state\n    __typename\n  }\n  marketCenter {\n    market_center_name\n    market_center_address1\n    market_center_address2\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n"
}

headers = {
    "x-datadog-trace-id":"3293080049736028717",
    "x-datadog-origin":"rum",
    "x-datadog-sampling-priority":"1",
    "x-datadog-parent-id":"8148745964431063043",
    "x-shared-secret":"MjFydHQ0dndjM3ZAI0ZHQCQkI0BHIyM=",
    "x-datadog-sampled":"1"
}


result = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
obj = json.loads(result.text)
edges = obj['data']['SearchAgentQuery']['result']['agents']['edges'][0]
print(edges['node']['name']['full'])
```

This code will grab all 652 agents at once and prints the full name of the first agent. One agent looks like this in the response:

```json
"node": {
        "id": "UPA-6762861760017670144-8",
        "name": {
            "full": "Maryam Abdi",
            "given": "Maryam",
            "initials": "MA",
            "__typename": "BasePersonNameType"
        },
        "image": "https://storage.googleapis.com/attachment-prod-e2ad/754026/c7grro22skjb1jt7u73g.jpg",
        "location": {
            "address": {
                "state": "IL",
                "city": "Chicago",
                "__typename": "AddressType"
            },
            "__typename": "LocatorType"
        },
        "realEstateEntity": null,
        "specialties": [],
        "languages": [
            "English"
        ],
        "isAgentLuxuryEnabled": false,
        "phone": {
            "entries": [
                {
                    "__typename": "ContactSetEntryLandline"
                },
                {
                    "number": "4253753652",
                    "__typename": "ContactSetEntryMobile"
                },
                {
                    "email": "maryam.abdi@kw.com",
                    "__typename": "ContactSetEntryEmail"
                }
            ],
            "__typename": "ContactSetType"
        },
        "agentLicenses": [
            {
                "licenseNumber": "PENDING",
                "state": "IL",
                "__typename": "AgentLicense"
            }
        ],
        "marketCenter": {
            "market_center_name": "KW ONEChicago ",
            "market_center_address1": "2211 N. Elston Suite 104",
            "market_center_address2": "Chicago IL 60614",
            "__typename": "MarketingProfileMarketCenterType"
        },
        "__typename": "AgentProfileType"
    },
    "__typename": "AgentProfileEdge"
}
```

To find out which requests your browser makes, you can simply filter out requests in the `Network` tab `Fetch/XHR`. One of them is called `graphql` which is the important one.

I can recommend [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) and the associated [browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo).

If you don't want grab all agents at once or don't know how many there are.
The response of all requests to the graphql endpoint contains a `pageInfo` which has the fields `endCursor` and `hasNextPage`.

```json
"pageInfo": {
    "endCursor": "49",
    "hasNextPage": true,
    "__typename": "PageInfo"
}
```

Now you can check if `hasNextPage` is true if so, do another request. In each following request the field `after` in your payload must be set to the `endCursor` value of the previous Request.

For example:

```py
result = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
obj = json.loads(result.text)
pageInfo = obj['data']['SearchAgentQuery']['result']['agents']['pageInfo']
while pageInfo['hasNextPage']:
    # do something with the data
    # For example print full names:
    edges = obj['data']['SearchAgentQuery']['result']['agents']['edges']
    for edge in edges:
        print(edge['node']['name']['full'])
    # update the after value
    after = pageInfo['endCursor']
    payload['variables']['after'] = after
    # new request
    result = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
    obj = json.loads(result.text)
    pageInfo = obj['data']['SearchAgentQuery']['result']['agents']['pageInfo']

# do something with the data of the last request
```

Obviously you need to change the `first` field to a smaller number e.g. 50
Output:

```
Maryam Abdi
Ariana Abercrumbie
STEVE ACOBA
McKinley Adams
Lenora Adds
Maruf Adeyemo
Angela Akins
Henriette Akins
Melanie Alcaraz
Kira Alexander
Biekhal Alkhalifa
Maria Allen
Stephanie Allen
Alejandro Almaraz
Mark Altamore
Adam Alvanos
Peter Ambrosino
...
```

Comment: There are so many requests that are being made, how did you know this was the exact api on which data request was being made?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar If you are using Chrome you can filter out `Fetch/XHR` requests. On of the request is called `graphql`. Thats the one

Comment: hmm so I was thinking if it is so obvious, why don't we scrape all pages using this method only? like get the actual end point that is hit  along with the header and payload and make the request ourselves?

Comment: Also I see more content are generated on scroll, how can we make the request further, what option needs to be changed here?

Comment: Because a proper grapql endpoint will be protected, hence the need for selenium from time to time (in this case it is not protected). Also, overall selenium is a less complex solution, albeit a bit slower and more resources-hungry.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar As shown in my answer you can do multiple requests and get e.g. 50 each request until none is left. You only need to check the `hasNextPage` and `endCursor` fields. And change the `after` field in your payload after each request. In my answer you can see an example

Comment: @noah1400 I need some time to understand this code (sorry I'm new learner). Can you please tell me what need to change in here to showing the 652 names `edges = obj['data']['SearchAgentQuery']['result']['agents']['edges'][0]`

Comment: @RasedulIslam In this case you need to iterate over `edges` so remove the `[0]`. And do something like `for edge in edges: ...`. I posted an example of how such an edge looks like. In your for loop do this: `print(edge['node']['name']['full'])`

Comment: @noah1400 Your explanation is perfect. I understand now and learned a new way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can extract all the names from the page by going over all the agent cards.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://kw.com/agent/search/IL/Chicago'
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"

s = Service(chrome_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get(url)
agent_names = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'AgentCard')
for agent in agent_names:
    print(agent.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'AgentCard__name').text)
```

This gives us

```
Maryam Abdi
Ariana Abercrumbie
STEVE ACOBA
McKinley Adams
Lenora Adds
Maruf Adeyemo
Angela Akins
Henriette Akins
Melanie Alcaraz
Kira Alexander
Biekhal Alkhalifa
Maria Allen
Stephanie Allen
Alejandro Almaraz
Mark Altamore
Adam Alvanos
Peter Ambrosino
Miguel Amesquita
Deval Amin
Steve Anderson
Alicia Andrade
Brittany Andrews
Sandy Andros
Christopher Anthony
Joel Anthony
Perry Apawu
Mark Apel
Niko Apostal
Vashti Araia
Joe Ariano
Charlie Arnold
Harjit Ashta
John P. Astorina
Sharron Atterberry
Dave Auffarth
David Augustyn
Joseph Avola
Ravid Ayala
Shavell Banks
Julie Bapst
Maria Barba
Christina Barbaro
Deonte Barbee
Adam Bartosic
Stephanie Basa
Bart Basinski
Nicole Basso
Peter Batarseh
Nicholas Batsakis
Steven Battista
```

Answer (score 1):

The requests module brings the pure html page (without javascript). So you'll need to use selenium instead.

For instance:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://kw.com/agent/search/IL/Chicago'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

chrome_path = which('chromedriver')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, options=chrome_options)

driver.get(url)

links = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, value="a")
```

Comment: It's showing "NameError: name 'which' is not defined".  How can i solve this?

Comment: @RasedulIslam I've eddited my answer... try now... in my case, i put chromedriver in the same folder